# Error when assigning api-response(data) to global variable

Tags: swift

I am trying to assign the "API" response data to my global variable "sökresultat", but it gives me the error "ERROR - Missing arugment for parameter "from" in call, insert from <#decoder#>".

I read something about having to initialize my struct, but dont think that's the problem? I'm a beginner at swift and would love if someone would just point me in the right direction.

**Part of viewcontroller file:**

```
// MARK: - Extension functions
extension Sökruta{


var sökresultat = Main2()    // ERROR - Missing arugment for parameter "from" in call, insert from <#decoder#>



    // MARK: - API GET REQUEST
    func GetRequest(Url: String)  {

        AF.request(result, headers: headers).validate().responseJSON { response in

            // MARK: - Check for errors
            if let error = response.error
            {}

            // MARK: - Print response
            if response.response != nil
            {}

            // MARK: - Print data
            if response.data != nil
            {
              let decoder = JSONDecoder()
               do
            {
                let api = try decoder.decode(Main2.self, from: response.data!)

                self.sökresultat = api // I WANT TO ASSIGN "API" TO MY GLOBAL VARIABLE sökresultat above




            }

               catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                   print("Error in JSON parsing")
               } } } }// MARK: - END





}
```

**Struct file:**

```
// MARK: - Main2
struct Main2: Codable {
    let meta: Meta2
    let objects: [Object2]
}

// MARK: - Meta2
struct Meta2: Codable {
    let status: String
    let count, offset, totalcount: Int
}

// MARK: - Object2
struct Object2: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let url: String
    let displayname: String
    let media: [Media2]
}

// MARK: - Media2
struct Media2: Codable {
    let id, prodno: Int
    let webpath: String
    let slot: Int
    let type, extdata: String
    let ctime, xsize, ysize, mediasetid: Int
    let alt, title: String
    let generation: Int
    let created, changed: String
}
```

Comment: Declare like this : var sökresultat: Main2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there is a second error in the same line which doesn't appear yet:

> Extensions must not contain stored properties

Declare `sökresultat` directly in the view controller. If it's guaranteed that a value is assigned before it's being used declare it as implicit unwrapped optional

```
var sökresultat : Main2!
```

otherwise as regular optional

```
var sökresultat : Main2?
```

---

Side note:

Never

```
print(error.localizedDescription)
```

in a `JSONDecoder` catch block, you'll get a generic meaningless error message, instead always

```
print(error)
```

And please conform to the naming convention: Methods/functions and variable names start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the side note, much appreciated.